# Spring Response\Request body templates

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Let me explain a problem. Suppose I have an entity class `User`:

```java
public class User {
  private UUID id;
  private String login;
  private String password;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String email;
  private int age;
  // ... more fields and default getters and setters
}
```

In addition, I have two DTO classes:

```java
public class UserLogin {
  private UUID id;
  private String login;
  // ... getters and setters
}

public class UserLoginEmail {
  private UUID id;
  private String login;
  private String email;
  // ... getters and setters
}
```

Let's take a look to class `UserController` that has `UserLoginEmail` as request body and `UserLogin` as response body:

```java
@RestController("/users")
public class UserController {

  @PutMapping
  public UserLogin someRequest(UserLoginEmail user) {
      // ...
  }

}
```

What is the best way to create some kind of [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.5.6/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) in Spring Boot? Can I create an interface with required fields and just put them in the Java method as parameters (or some other way)? I want to build DTO classes with the least effort and agile in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON Views with Jackson with which you could define different views on a per endpoint basis (check https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation for more details).

But in your case, I wouldn't do that. One of your DTOs is a request and the other is a response so you shouldn't mix them together in a single DTO. Even more than that, I don't really like JSON Views because they are simply hard to follow and the code becomes harder to read. Abstractions and code reusability are usually good but it makes the code much harder to read and for the case of DTOs I much more prefer to be explicit and have multiple DTOs even that they are similar. With this approach, you will make it possible to easily change one of the DTOs without affecting anything else, which is not the case when you reuse them in any way.

Having said that, keep both DTOs, but I would rename them: `UserLoginRequest` and `UserLoginResponse`.

Comment: I see, thank you!